# How would I pivot this type of data in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, aggregate, grouping

I have a query which generates results such as this

```
 ID | Column2 | Sentence
----|---------|---------
1   | SameVal |This is a sentence
1   | SameVal |This is another unique sentence
1   | SameVal |A third unique sentence
2   | SameVal |This is a sentence
2   | SameVal |This is another unique sentence
2   | SameVal |A third unique sentence
3   | SameVal |This is a sentence
3   | SameVal |This is another unique sentence
3   | SameVal |A third unique sentence
```

Is it possible that I could pivot this data somehow so that my results are like so

```
 ID | Column2 | Sentence
----|---------|---------
1   | SameVal |This is a sentence
2   | SameVal |This is another unique sentence
3   | SameVal |A third unique sentence
```

Query below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    t1.ID, t2.Department, t1.ReportMonth, t2.Supplier,
    t1.RepID, t1.CustomerID, t4.Sentence
FROM 
    table1 t1
JOIN 
    table2 t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID
JOIN 
    table3 rt ON rt.LookupCd = t1.ProgramCD
JOIN 
    table4 t4 ON t4.CustomerID = t1.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN 
    table5 t5 ON t1.CustomerID = t5.CustomerID
WHERE
    t1.code = 'ax' AND
    t2.program = 'qx' AND
    t1.date = '7/7/12'
```

Comment: Distinct? Group by? would be helpful if you showed us your query...

Comment: I'm using distinct. I've added an example of the query. I can't post the identical query.

Comment: According to which rule is ID 1 connected to *"This is a sentence"*, ID 2 to *"...another..."* and ID 3 to *"A third..."*?

Comment: The sentence is supposed to come from table4 or t4.

Answer (score 0):

You still can try DISTINCT or GROUP BY:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM
(
    SELECT t1.ID,t2.Department,t1.ReportMonth,t2.Supplier,t1.RepID,t1.CustomerID,t4.Sentence
    FROM table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID
    JOIN table3 rt ON rt.LookupCd = t1.ProgramCD
    JOIN table4 t4 ON t4.CustomerID = t1.CustomerID
    LEFT JOIN table5 t5 ON t1.CustomerID = t5.CustomerID
    WHERE
        t1.code = 'ax' AND
        t2.program = 'qx' AND
        t1.date = '7/7/12'
) t
```

or

```
SELECT t1.ID,t2.Department,t1.ReportMonth,t2.Supplier,t1.RepID,t1.CustomerID,t4.Sentence
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID
JOIN table3 rt ON rt.LookupCd = t1.ProgramCD
JOIN table4 t4 ON t4.CustomerID = t1.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN table5 t5 ON t1.CustomerID = t5.CustomerID
WHERE
    t1.code = 'ax' AND
    t2.program = 'qx' AND
    t1.date = '7/7/12'
GROUP BY t1.ID,t2.Department,t1.ReportMonth,t2.Supplier,t1.RepID,t1.CustomerID,t4.Sentence
```

Comment: But they're all distinct because each ID (1, 2, 3) has it's own set of  corresponding sentences.

Comment: Yeah, I would say that your solution should work too. But you can try mine just in case. And btw, in your example you dont need t5.